# Classifying the state space of the Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, self-learning, markov-process

Classify the state space of the Markov chain with following transition probability matrix into communicating classes:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
0.2& 0.2 &0.6& 0\\
0.6 &0.2& 0.1& 0.1\\
0.3 &0.3& 0.3 &0.1\\
1.0& 0& 0& 0
\end{array}
\right] $$

**My Solution:**

Doesn't this Markov chain have only one communicating class $\{0,1,2,3\}$ since $0\rightarrow1\rightarrow2\rightarrow3$, hence this is an irreducible Markov chain?

Comment: You are right but you should have written $0\rightarrow1\rightarrow2\rightarrow3\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is right. This Markov chain has got only 1 communication class and this is irreducible  Markov chain